# jQuery Deferred Ajax Calls and Returning Ajax Responses

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, deferred

I am making a synchronous AJAX call in jQuery now. Is there any way for a parent function to return an Ajax response while maintaining an async call. The only solution I was able to find out was using a call back function. I don’t really want to write a callback function as I intend to take this object in a variable.

For example

```
var ajax = serviceinterface.rawServiceCall(“http://user.myservice.com/endpoint”, “post”, {name : “xyz”});
```

I might also want to use it like this

```
$.when(serviceinterface.rawServiceCall(endpoint1, “get”), serviceinterface.rawSCACall(endpoint2, ‘get’)).done(function(){
    // do something here
});
```

Here is my function code, synchronous call works absolutely fine but I want to make an asynchronous call.

```
rawServiceCall : function(endpoint, type, payload) {
                     type = typeof type !== 'undefined' ? type : "get";
                     payload = typeof type !== 'undefined' ? payload : null;

                     return $.ajax({
                           url : endpoint,
                           type : type,
                           data : payload,
                           async : false,
                           dataType : 'json',
                           headers: {
                                 accept : "application/json"
                           },
                           success : function(data){
                                 return data;
                           }
                    });

              }
```

P.S - I don’t want to waste CPU cycles or keep the other parts of the webpage waiting for this to load first. Or what’s the better approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no. Behaviour will be either wholly synchronous or wholly asynchronous.

But I don't think you have a problem because your code is 99% of the solution you seek. You just need to know how to assess the returned `data` in the `.done()` callback.

The answer is that the `.done()` callback takes arguments identical to those in a `success` callback defined as an ajax option, ie. `data`, `textStatus` and `jqXHR`.

```
rawServiceCall: function(endpoint, type, payload) {
    type = type || "get";
    payload = payload || null;
    return $.ajax({
        url: endpoint,
        type: type,
        data: payload,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            accept: "application/json"
        }
    });
}

serviceinterface.rawServiceCall(endpoint1).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //do something here
});

$.when(serviceinterface.rawServiceCall(endpoint1), serviceinterface.rawServiceCall(endpoint2)).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // do something here
});
```

The same is true of `error` and `complete` callbacks, so the full list of callback equivalents for a jQuery.ajax promise is :

- `.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){...})` is equivalent to `success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){...}`
- `.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){...})` is equivalent to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){...}`
- `.always(function((jqXHR, textStatus){...})` is equivalent to `complete: function((jqXHR, textStatus){...}`

Every jQuery promise object has `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.always()` methods, but the arguments taken by these methods' callbacks (if any) vary depending on what is passed when the original Deferred (from which the promise is derived) is resolved/rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an async method into sync in JavaScript **without** wasting CPU cycles.

The only way to stop executing code is with an alert(). In JS never do you sleep, you just idle.